# Stuck with a signal SIGABRT error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting this error when running my app on Xcode 5, beta 5. New to the programing scene and looking for some guidance. Any help is appreciated.

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x55d8, 0x38c9b1f0 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x38c9b1f0 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
    frame #1: 0x38d037b6 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 58
    frame #2: 0x38c4bff8 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 76
    frame #3: 0x3807e98e libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 74
    frame #4: 0x380976e6 libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate_handler() + 254
    frame #5: 0x386caf7c libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 192
    frame #6: 0x380951b2 libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 78
    frame #7: 0x38094d16 libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 102
    frame #8: 0x386cae2e libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 42
    frame #9: 0x2dc8f81e CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 642
    frame #10: 0x2dc8f58a CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    frame #11: 0x3077a43a UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 762
    frame #12: 0x307756d8 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1136
  * frame #13: 0x00058e80 MedicalCodes`main(argc=1, argv=0x27db1cfc) + 116 at main.m:16
(lldb)
```

Here is the error I am getting via using the break point.

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {
        DetailViewController *detailviewcontroller = [segue destinationViewController];

```
    NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    int row = [myIndexPath row];
    detailviewcontroller.DetailModal = @[_Title[row], _Description[row]]; <-- its on this line of code right here.
```

says unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e6a180
Any help?

Comment: cant you point it down to specific region of code in your app when this error occurs ? or it comes on launch ?

Comment: SIGABRT generally means that the program threw an exception. could you please provide additional information like some code blocks etc.

Comment: use breaking point to find actual error and post to your question

Answer (score 7):

Add Exception Breakpoint and then run the project. In most cases exception breakpoint will stop at the line of code which causes the problem.

[image]

You can also do this from  Debug > Breakpoints > Create Exception Breakpoint...

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSZombieEnabled = YES;`

That might give you a exact error report

Comment: And where to do so?